# Select only a specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to retrieve only a specific range inside an excel sheet.

My table is as follows:

[image]

The selection should be 4 columns and 7 rows. From `A3 to D9`

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What you need excatly...?

Comment: vba code for it, the number of columns and rows can vary.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please [edit] your original question and add the code you tried. This is not a free coding service. Asking others to write the code for you without showing what you already tried is just a bad habit. At least provide detailed and good information of what you try to achieve and where you exactly got stuck. Otherwise this is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you have a specific data area surrounded by garbage. To select a specific range you need to specify the top left and the right bottom cells. In this case I would hunt for special cells which are: bold headers and at least one empty cell under each column. So try this:

```
for each c in usedrange  ' row by row so finds the top left bold cell
      if c.font.bold then exit for      ' found
next c
if c.font.bold then 
     toprow = c.row
     leftcol = c.column
endif
' now search for right col
for i=leftcol to leftcol+100
    if not cells(toprow, i).font.bold then exit for
next i
if i < leftcol + 100 then rightcol = i - 1
' now search the bottom row
bottomrow = 0
for i = leftcol to rigthcol
    for r = toprow to toprow + 500
         if cells(r, i) = vbnullstring then exit for
    next r
    if bottomrow < r then bottomrow = r
next i
' now we have all data
Range(Cells(toprow, leftcol), Cells(bottomrow, rightcol).Select
```

This is just a raw minimum, you'll need add a few more lines to initialize vars, handle else branches and 0 values, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:D9").Select
```

Comment: the count of rows and columns may vary.

Comment: @user2281858 The problem is "*retrieve only a specific range*" does not describe which range you mean and how it would be determined. You need to be very specific here. The computer can not know what you want if you don't tell him what **exactly** to do. You need to teach him first **how** to find that range if columns and rows vary. How would you determine how many rows and columns are the range you want? Explain that as detailed as possible in your original question (not in a comment)!

Comment: @user2281858 Question states "The selection should be 4 columns and 7 rows. From A3 to D9", so why does your comment say "the count of rows and columns may vary"?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
newrange = lCol & ":" & lrow
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(newrange).Select
```

Edited:
if the table is in middle of the sheet. Just change the value from `1` to the desired value. For Example if the `row=2` and `Column=3`, then the `lCol` and `lrow` will be changed as follows

```
lCol = Cells(**3**, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, **2**).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: @nishit.dey it will return all the rows and columns

Comment: Can you be clear on the requirements. Thanks. I am not able to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using the Find method:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
DateColumn = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Date").Column
'find the column which contains Date
DateRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Date").Row
'find the row which contains Date
QuantityRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Quantity").Row
'find the row which contains Quantity
ws.Range(ws.Cells(DateRow, DateColumn), ws.Cells(LastRow, QuantityColumn)).Select
End Sub
```